# It is possible to create multiple toolbars in Ubuntu 14.04, not just the default one?

Tags: unity

I would like to know if is possible to have more than one toolbar to put more icons or kind of shortcuts.

I have searched for this but i have not found anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't creating quicklists, grouping apps and/or commands in the current launcher solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I presume by toolbar, you mean the launcher on the left side of the screen in Unity.

No, it is not possible to create more versions of the launcher. However, it is scrollable, so if you overflow, the icons will fold at the bottom, and you can fit more items in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible.  There are other taskbar utilities out there, and other flavors of Ubuntu like Kubuntu or Lubuntu may have support for that.  As an alternative, you can place items onto your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Docky from the Software Center.  It is a launcher, and you can configure it's position and appearance.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/docky/